# jsforce Apex REST call fails in IE11 only. ES6 Promise support issue?

Tags: apexrest, jsforce, promises, ie-11

I am calling a custom Apex REST endpoint from JS in a **custom VF component** within a VF page using the jsforce library, and everything works as expected in Edge, Chrome, Firefox, but **not IE11**. It seems to be an issue with Promises, but there are no error messages in the console; it fails silently. The **Apex code is executing successfully in the backend, but the jsforce post method's returned callback isn't invoked.** In the snippet below, 'log1' shows but not 'log2.'

```
function doStuff(val1) {
  ...

  console.log('log1'); // logged in console

  sfConnection.apex.post("/CustEndpoint/", postBody, function(err, res) {
      console.log('log2'); // logged for all browsers I support except IE11
      ...
  });
}
```

So the [Promise returned](https://jsforce.github.io/jsforce/doc/Apex.html) from the jsforce post method callback isn't being invoked in IE11 for some reason. I have tried adding a couple of Promise polyfills, including BluebirdJS and ES6-Promise to no avail.

Console logging the Promise object shows that the polyfills are injecting a definition for the Promise object, yet the callback from jsforce still isn't getting invoked.

Comment: related? [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008pLgQAI)

Comment: Interesting, but seems doubtful. This is a VF component with in a VF page running in Classic, not a Lightning component. I'll update my post to specify. Thank you! Wonder if it could be related despite being in VF

Comment: its what i thought, but just so you know it exists, and maybe its not specific to lightning after all (we had originally logged a case related to lightning, they maybe didn't validate in VF pages )

Comment: I think Lightning Framework actually includes a Promise polyfill all on its own making it redundant to add another of your own. So yeah this issue is probably a whole other ballgame.

Comment: Looking at the `package.json` for jsforce I see it has a dependency on PromiseJS (https://www.promisejs.org/). Indeed if you look at the browser JS file for it, there are signs that it embeds a definition of Promise. In any case it's probably best to check in with the author of jsforce on this too.

Comment: However it attempts to include a Promise polyfill it doesn't seem to be working in IE11.  At the time of the jsforce conn.apex.post() function invocation _Promise_ is undefined `console.log(typeof Promise == "undefined"); //true` whereas _conn_ is defined `console.log(typeof Promise == "undefined"); //false` by the jsforce library